# Fast in-memory inverted index

Tags: indexing, lucene, lucene.net, information-retrieval

I am looking for a fast in-memory implementation of a generic inverted index. All I need is to store features with weights for a couple million entities and use the inverted index to compute similarities between entities using various distance functions.

All other attributes of entities I can store in some fast key-value store.

I hoped I could use Lucene just as an inverted index, but cannot see how I can associate with a document my own custom feature vector with precomputed weights.  Any recommendations would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "custom feature vector with precomputed weights"? Lucene has boost, not sure if that's what you're after.

Comment: Currently my features are n-grams and entities extracted from a collection of ~ 2 million documents. I have my own pipeline that compute feature scores (currently tf-idf) and generate an inverted index as a flat text file (feature -> [doc1: score, doc2: score, ...]). I want to load all these features into some fast in-memory data store that will allow me to do similarity search and KNN by feature vector under dozens milliseconds. No network calls. I have my own solution which is read-only inverted-index based on memory mapped files, but wanted to see if there is something else that I can use.

Comment: You can store the various fields with individual "boosts" or boost a document for your feature scores. Lucene just might cut it. Another option would be Mongo DB.

Answer (score 5):

I have been doing some similar work and have discovered that redis' zset is pretty much what I need (though I am not actually using it right now; I have rolled my own solution based on memory mapped files). 

Basically a zset is a sorted set of key-value pairs. 

So you can have a sorted set per feature where each 
feature->[ { docid, score }, {docid, score} ..]
i.e. 
zadd feature score docid

redis then has some nice operators to merge, extract ranges etc. See zunionstore, zrange (http://redis.io/commands/zunionstore).

Very fast (supposedly) and all in memory etc ... (though redis is not an embedded db).

Comment: Thank you. This is interesting information. My scenario changed and I needed to use an embedded db, so I also ended up building my custom implementation with memory mapped files. Kind of an in-memory graph for IR.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Terrier](http://terrier.org/)? I'm not quite sure it has in-memory indexes, but it is far more extensible regarding indexing and scoring than Lucene.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene lets you store pretty much any data associated with a document.  It also has a feature called "payloads" that allow you to store arbitrary data in the index associated with a term in a document.  So I think what you want is to store your "features" as terms in the index, and the weights as payloads, and you should be able to make Lucene do what you want.  It does have an in-memory index implementation.

Comment: Are there any c++ inverted index solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If the pairs of entities you want to compare are already given in advance, and you are interested in the pair-wise scores, I don't think Lucene will give you any advantage. Just lookup the vectors in some key-value store and compute the similarity. Consider using a sparse vector representation for space and time efficiency.

If only one entity is given in advance, and you are more interested in a ranking like scenario, Lucene may be worth a try. 
The right place to look at would be

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Similarity
```

you should be able to adapt it to your needs and set your version as default with

```
setDefault(Similarity similarity)
```

I would be careful with expectations for speed gains (w.r.t. iterating through all) however, as they largely depend on the sparsity (of the query) and the scoring function you choose to implement. Also note that Lucene uses a two-stage retrieval scheme, first boolean ("all of the AND terms contained? any of the OR terms?") then scoring what passes. While for tf.idf you lose nothing on the way for other scoring functions you might.

For more general approaches for efficient approximate nearest neighbor search it might be worthwhile to look into LSH:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing